# SQL query for date format

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a dateFormat 2017-08-17T12:08:00(YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS) and I want to convert it to 2017-08-17T00:00:00-05:00.Write a sql query to run on sql developer.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort!

Answer (score 0):

if you are use sql server 8 or latest then u can use system function "FORMAT" like this :

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd"T"00:00:00-hh:MM')
```

Result : 2017-10-12T00:00:00-03:10

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the TO_CHAR (datetime) function which can convert your datetime to a VARCHAR2 datatype in the format you have specified.